# Using images in QListWidget, is this possible?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I am using QT to create a chat messenger client. To display the list of online users, I'm using a `QListWidget`, as created like this:

```
listWidget = new QListWidget(horizontalLayoutWidget);
listWidget->setObjectName("userList");
QSizePolicy sizePolicy1(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0);
sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0);
sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(listWidget->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
listWidget->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1);
listWidget->setMinimumSize(QSize(30, 0));
listWidget->setMaximumSize(QSize(150, 16777215));
listWidget->setBaseSize(QSize(100, 0));
listWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

Users are shown by constantly refreshing the list, like this: (Note: There are different channels, with different userlists, so refreshing it is the most efficient thing to do, as far as I know.)

```
void FMessenger::refreshUserlist()
{
    if (currentPanel == 0)
        return;
    listWidget = this->findChild<QListWidget *>(QString("userList"));
    listWidget->clear();
    QList<FCharacter*> charList = currentPanel->charList();
    QListWidgetItem* charitem = 0;
    FCharacter* character;
    foreach(character, charList)
    {
        charitem = new QListWidgetItem(character->name());
        // charitem->setIcon(QIcon(":/Images/status.png"));
        listWidget->addItem(charitem);
    }
}
```

This has always worked perfectly. The line that I commented out is the one I have problems with: my current goal is to be able to display a user's online status with an image, which represents whether they are busy, away, available, etc. Using `setIcon()` does absolutely nothing though, apparently; the items still show up as they used to, without icons.

I'm aware that this is probably not the way this function needs to be used, but I have found little documentation about it online, and absolutely no useful examples of implementations. My question is, can anybody help me with fixing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you may conduct your debugging:

- Try the constructor that has both icon and text as arguments.
- Try to use that icon in another context to ensure it is displayable (construct a QIcon with same argument and use it elsewhere, e.g. QLabel!).
- Use icon() from the QListWidgetItem to receive back the icon and then look at that QIcon.
- Create a new QListWidget, change nothing, and ordinarily add some stock items in your MainWidget's constructor. See if the icons show up there.

Comment: Does this mean that you think it should work, but has a bug somewhere? I'm weighing some options, one of them being by simply trying something completely different, but it seems like this is not needed, then?

Comment: Yes, it should definitely work. Even the documentation of QListWidget shows items with icons. See also these code samples: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_use_QListWidget_and_QListWidgetItem http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Getting_image_from_list_in_Qt_for_Symbian

Comment: This is quite embarrassing, in fact... The problem was caused by a capitalization fault somewhere. I work together with some other people via SVN, and apparently part of the resource system was made in Windows, where the distinction between lower and upper case is not always made. Thanks for the help though! I'm glad I didn't overthrow the whole thing.